# Calling the method reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

My app includes two collectionViews , `mainCollectionView` and `nestedCollectionView` which is in the `mainCollectionViewCell` .

It's like the iPhone calendar app , each cell in the `mainCollectionView` has `nestedCollectionView` which represents a month(the number of the cells will be the number of the month days).

```
class cell_Main:UICollectionViewCell{

    let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let cv = nestedCollectionView()
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        return cv
    }()
```

to update the `nestedcollectionView` if the month changes , I"ve used  `nestedcollectionView.reloadData()` inside the method(which belongs to mainCollectionView ):

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell_main", for: indexPath) as! cell_Main

        let nested_CollectionView = cell.collectionView as! nestedCollectionView
               .
               .
               .
         nested_CollectionView.reloadData()

}
```

! *if I scroll the `mainCollectionView`, the `nestedCollectionView` supposed to be updated (the month will be changed).*

my question: the code works fine , but is it the right way to `reloadData()` here?, does it an expensive CPU work, does the app use too much CPU?

Comment: Can you do this by some other way?

Comment: I think it depends what you do or have in the nested cells, and I think you are fine with just having a label inside them but you can always monitor the cpu and find it yourself on Xcode debug navigator. but my recommendation is to reload your collectionViews inside dispatchQueue to update them in asynchronous way.

Comment: actually I used before one collection view and two buttons(lift and right) which update the month , then the reloadData() will be inside the buttons actions , in this way I can limit the user scrolling unnecessary scrolls. but somehow it is the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using nested Collection View which represent month in a year , I've tried to make one Main CollectionView , and the number of sections will be 12 (*the months number*) , each section represent month and in each section the `numberOfItemsInSection` will be the month days number . and any updation can be here(without using `reloadData()`):

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
}
```

.finally when we scroll down to the end section we would call `reloadData()` to update the new `numberOfSections` and move to the next year .